# Allocated Memory and Reserved Memory of Application Master

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to understand the 'Allocated Memory' and 'Reserve Memory' columns that are present in the screenshot. [Screenshot from Application Master in YARN UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hijFK.png)

[image]

The cluster settings that I have done in YARN are:

```
yarn_nodemanager_resource_memory-mb: 16GB
yarn_scheduler_minimum-allocation-mb: 256MB
yarn_scheduler_increment-allocation-mb: 500MB
yarn_scheduler_maximum-allocation-mb: 16GB
```

It is a single node cluster having 32GB of memory in total and 6 vCores.

Now, you can see from the screenshot that the 'Allocated Memory' is 8500MB. I would like to know how this is getting calculated.

One more thing - the driver memory specified is spark.driver.memory=10g

Comment: share spark-submit command

Comment: I have sent the scala code via Livy. So, spark-submit is not used for submission of job.

Answer (score 0):

Allocated memory is either determined by:

- The memory available in your cluster
- The memory available in your queue
- vCores * (executor memory + executor overhead)

In your case it looks like your allocated memory is limited by the third option. I'm guessing you didn't set spark.executor.memory or spark.executor.memoryOverhead because the memory you are getting is right in line with the default values. [The Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) show that default values are:

- spark.executor.memory = 1g
- spark.executor.memoryOverhead = 0.1 * executor memory with a minimum of 384mb

This gives about 1400mb per core which multiple by your 6 cores lines up with the Allocated Memory you are seeing